# Compile Ada sources without the shared libraries

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, static-libraries, ada

How can I compile the `Hello World` program from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_%28programming_language%29#.22Hello.2C_world.21.22_in_Ada) on a [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) environment and run it on a [uclibc](http://www.uclibc.org/) environment?

```
localhost:~$ readelf -d /home/localhost/hello | grep NEEDED
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at dlopen() library set of functions. You'll need to load the libraries from the source file itself. The following code is in C, but you can use Interafaces.C in Ada to interoperate with C libraries:

```
lib_handle = dlopen("/opt/lib/libctest.so", RTLD_LAZY);
if (!lib_handle) 
{
   fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
   exit(1);
}
```

Visit this [link](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html) for help. This [man page dlopen(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) should also help.